# Javascript, Prototype and Inherit

Tags: javascript

I've this code:

```
var Parent = function(){};
var Child = function(){};

function inherit(C, P){
    C.prototype = new P();//received a pointer to Parent
    C.prototype.test = function(){};
}

inherit(Child, Parent);
console.log(new Parent);//Object {}
console.log(new Child);//Object {test=function()}
```

Now i've a question, if C.prototype received a pointer to Parent in my inherit function, why my "console.log(new Parent)" doesn't show like this: "Object {test=function()}" to Parent and "Object {}" to Child?

Comment: From an instance you can't write to the prototype (maybe with the non standard __proto__ property but would nor advice it) more explanation here:http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941 it is better to not create an instance of Parent to set up the prototype part of inheritance

Comment: i will not use this code, i just wrote it to show what i wanted to show, but thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 3):

Taken out the function to simplify;

```
var Parent = function(){};
var Child = function(){};

Child.prototype = new Parent();//"received a pointer to Parent"
Child.prototype.test = function(){};

console.log(new Parent);//Object {}
console.log(new Child);//Object {test=function()}
```

`Child.prototype` is now a reference to an *instance* of a `Parent`, to illustrate, what you did could also be written as:

```
var Parent = function(){};
var Child = function(){};

var instance = new Parent();
instance.test = function(){};
Child.prototype = instance;

console.log(new Parent);//Object {}
console.log(new Child);//Object {test=function()}
```

Putting properties on the instance does not affect the `Parent` prototype, which is why the console log doesn't show the test function on the `Parent` prototype. It would be the same as doing ( *almost* the same ):

```
var instance = {
    test: function(){}
};
instance.prototype = Parent;
```

Comment: I don't understand, because if the instance is receiving a pointer to "new Parent()", in my logic, if everything you put in this instance you're pointing to Parent, i don't know what javascript does behind the scenes.

Comment: The same is for example with `Object`, when you do `new Object()` and assign properties to it, it does not affect the `Object` prototype, only that instance of the object you have. The instance inherits from the prototype, the prototype is not affected by changes to instances

Comment: yes, but i want to know why this happens, because in my C logic, if you receive a pointer, a reference, everything that you do with this pointer will impact directly in the reference.

Answer (score 1):

The `new P()`, creates a new space in ram and stores a P instance.
 Don't forget you change `C.(new P).test`, not `C.P.test`, there is difference. `new P` and `P` have different pointers, same as `new P` with `new P`. Check what does the `new` keyword in OOP like Java and then you will clear it out.

Answer (score 0):

To understand this better you have to know the difference between mutating an object and re assigning it.

```
a=22;//assigns value to a
a.something=22;//mutates it
a.push(22);//if a is an array then push will mutate it
```

As explained in my [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941) in the comments: you can't re assign prototype members through instances (Child.prototype is an **instance** of Parent) but you can mutate them (I advice reading the link posted). Here is some sample code:

```
var Test = function(){};
Test.prototype.something={a:1};
Test.prototype.somethingElse={a:2};
var t = new Test();
//mutating someting in t will change 
//  Test.prototype.someting
t.something.a=3;
//re assigning somethingElse will not
// change Test.prototype.somethingElse
// instead it will create a member called
// somethingElse on t 
t.somethingElse=3;
var anotherT =  new Test();
console.log(anotherT.something);//{a=3}
console.log(anotherT.somethingElse);//{a=2}
console.log(t.somethingElse);//3
console.log(t.hasOwnProperty("somethingElse"));//true
//next is false because anotherT.sometingElse comes
// from the prototype chain and not directly from antohrT
console.log(anotherT.hasOwnProperty("somethingElse"));//false
```

When passing variables to functions this works the same way:

```
var assignVal=function(obj){
  obj=22;
};
var mutateVal=function(obj){
  obj.mutated=22;
};

var o = {msg:"Hello World"};
assignVal(o);
console.log(o);//{msg="Hello world"}
mutateVal(o);
console.log(o);//{msg="Hello world",mutated=22}
```